# Using date separated colums to compare in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have three columns in a table to save a date, but now I need to compare those three columns as a date using the CONCAT and STR_TO_DATE function, but the comparision does not work, I don't see the error.

Query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(myyear,'-',mymonth,'-',myday),'%Y-%m-%d')>'2015-01-01'
```

Comment: Are you sure the columns contain valid values? I did a quick check, and replacing the columns by integers works.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, why not just use this?

```
select *
from mytable
where myyear >= 2015
```

Comment: The query is really more complex using more tables and subqueries and neccesarily I have to use the three columns